# What may be causing this WrongClassException Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2

I'm starting to work with Hibernate and I just got this exception that I don't know where to start to look.

I know the beginning of the Exception says "Error reading 'frotas' on type br.com.wplex.cccw.mbean.FrotaMBean", but thats because the error occurs inside the method getFrotas(), at more or less this query :

```
String hql = "from FrotaBO f order by f.aPartirDe".    
getHibernateSession().createQuery(hql).list();
```

Both DadosDeCobrancaBO and ClienteBO extend AbstractBO

Exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: /cadastros/Frota/frotaLista.xhtml @24,34 value="#{frotaBean.frotas}": Error reading 'frotas' on type br.com.wplex.cccw.mbean.FrotaMBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:157)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:176)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 3 was not of the specified subclass: br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.DadosDeCobrancaBO (loaded object was of wrong class class br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.ClienteBO)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceAlreadyLoaded(Loader.java:1307)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2082)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1853)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.GerenciadorTransacoes.pesquise(GerenciadorTransacoes.java:450)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.Dao.busca(Dao.java:69)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.FrotaDao.listaDeFrotas(FrotaDao.java:43)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.regras.RegrasDeFrota.listaTodasAsFrotasCadastradas(RegrasDeFrota.java:204)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.mbean.FrotaMBean.getFrotas(FrotaMBean.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    ... 53 more
29/05/2014 10:15:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/wplex3CW] threw exception [Object with id: 3 was not of the specified subclass: br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.DadosDeCobrancaBO (loaded object was of wrong class class br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.ClienteBO)] with root cause
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 3 was not of the specified subclass: br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.DadosDeCobrancaBO (loaded object was of wrong class class br.com.wplex.cccw.bo.ClienteBO)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceAlreadyLoaded(Loader.java:1307)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2082)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1853)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.GerenciadorTransacoes.pesquise(GerenciadorTransacoes.java:450)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.Dao.busca(Dao.java:69)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.dao.FrotaDao.listaDeFrotas(FrotaDao.java:43)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.regras.RegrasDeFrota.listaTodasAsFrotasCadastradas(RegrasDeFrota.java:204)
    at br.com.wplex.cccw.mbean.FrotaMBean.getFrotas(FrotaMBean.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:867)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:579)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:339)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:157)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:176)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: I think its problem caused coz of object fetched by query is of another type and code is trying to set in wrong class type? can you post your  DadosDeCobrancaBO,ClienteBO and AbstractBO classes?

Comment: Agree with @Amogh code given is not sufficient to understand. can you post code for what you are doing after getting result in `list()` like in which object you are setting result and structure for that class.

Comment: There's so many classes. Do I just post all of them here?

Comment: It even exceeds the 30000 limit.